# Why we must use a list in subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, subprocess, execve

My question is more theoretical than practical, I've found more answers that explains **how** but not **why** should we use a list in a `subprocess.Popen` call.

For example as is known:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02)
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> cmd = subprocess.Popen(["python", "-V"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
Python 2.7.10
```

Then I was messing around in UNIX and found something interesting:

```
mvarge@ubuntu:~$ strace -f python -V 2>&1
execve("/usr/bin/python", ["python", "-V"], [/* 29 vars */]) = 0
```

Probably both `execve` and the list model that `subprocess` use are someway related, but can anyone give a good explanation for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's convenient, for one thing.  When you have an argument that contains a space and two different kinds of quotation marks, it requires quite a bit to be able to put it in a string in such a way that Bash will treat it like one argument.  When it is in a list, `Popen` will take care of that for you.

Comment: As an aside, you should not normally use `subprocess.Popen()` - it happens to work in some cases on some platforms, but in the general case, it only *starts* a subprocess, and you need several additional interactions to then properly run and shutdown the process. The wrappers in the `subprocess` library take care of this, and shield you from the underlying complexities - only when they are inadequate for your needs should you turn to the underlying workhorse functions. In this case, `subprocess.call()` would be the tool of choice.

Answer (score 4):

The underlying C-level representation is a `*char []` array.  Representing this as a list in Python is just a very natural and transparent mapping.

You can use a string instead of a list with `shell=True`; the shell is then responsible for parsing the command line into a `* char []` array.  However, the shell adds a number of pesky complexities; see the many questions for [why you want to avoid `shell=True`](//stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) for a detailed explanation.

The [command line arguments `argv` and the environment `envp`](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html) are just two of many OS-level structures which are essentially a null-terminated arrays of strings.

Answer (score 3):

A *process* is an OS level abstraction — to create a process, you have to use OS API that dictates what you should use. **It is not necessary to use a list** e.g., a string (`lpCommandLine`) is the native interface [on Windows (`CreateProcess()`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx). [POSIX uses execv()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) and therefore the native interface is a sequence of arguments (`argv`). Naturally, `subprocess` Python module uses these interfaces to run external commands (create new processes).

The technical (uninsteresting) answer is that in *"why we must"*, the "must" part is not correct as Windows demonstrates.

To understand "why it *is*", you could ask the creators of `CreateProcess()`, `execv()` functions.

To understand "why we *should*" use a list, look at the table of contents for Unix (list) and Windows (string): [How Command Line Parameters Are Parsed](http://daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm) — the task that should be simple is complicated on Windows.

The main difference is that *on POSIX the caller* is responsible for splitting a command line into separate parameters. While *on Windows the command itself parses its parameters*. Different programs may and do use different algorithms to parse the parameters. [`subprocess` module uses MS C runtime rules (`subprocess.list2cmdline()`), to combine `args` list into the command line](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#converting-an-argument-sequence-to-a-string-on-windows). It is much harder for a programmer to understand how the parameters might be parsed on Windows.